# Only include a single directory in VSCode file watcher

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

- VSCode Version: 1.47.1
- Local OS Version: Windows 10.0.19041 N/A Build 19041
- Remote OS Version: NAME="Ubuntu" / VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
- Remote Extension/Connection Type: SSH

Upon connection, VSCode says

> "Unable to watch for file changes in this large workspace. Please
> follow the instructions link to resolve this issue."

which is explained in detail at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

I'd like to try limiting the file watcher's scope. I think it is currently trying to watch ALL the files in the server, not just my files in a small directory.

Official documentatoin says:

> Another option is to exclude specific workspace directories from the
> VS Code file watcher with the files.watcherExclude setting. The
> default for files.watcherExclude excludes node_modules and some
> folders under .git, but you can add other directories that you don't
> want VS Code to track.

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true   }
```

---

But my question is:

Where does file watcher "watch"? In what scope? Does it attempt to watch ALL the files in the server?
When I added these settings (actually, only below 2 lines) to .vscode/settings.json, file watcher warning STOPPED popping out.

```
"files.watcherExclude": {
    "**/.git/objects/**": true,
    "**/.git/subtree-cache/**": true,
    "**/node_modules/*/**": true,
    "**/.hg/store/**": true,

    "/**": true,
    "/home/my-user-name-john-doe/**": false
  }
```

I was trying to say: "Hey VSCode, stop watching all the file changes in the / root directories and only focus on MY directory."

Did I make myself clear here? Is the above settings does exactly what I was trying to say?

---

I'm getting an error that says:

Is it provoked by the changes in the `settings.json`?

[image]

Comment: Hello. In order to point you in the right direction, we need to know which operating system you are running.

Comment: @iskyfire Right, I added os info at the top.

Comment: I believe the error is originating from the `"/**"`. I do not believe you can place an exclusion starting from the root directory as it would prevent any files from being loaded.

The `"files.watcherExclude":` is mainly used if your code base is using a large amount of data files in a sub-directory, or if you have a sub-directory that contains another `node_modules` folder. I would check to see if you have any other `node_modules` folders, and if you do, exclude its parent folder. If that doesn't work, then we can instead look at the output of `cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Comment: Then, you can compare the output of `max_user_watches` to how many files are in your current project using `find . -type f | wc -l` on the remote server in the workspace directory. You can even remove folders from that search with `find . -type f -not -path '**/node_modules/**' | wc -l` to help you narrow down where the large amount of files may be coming from.

Comment: @iskyfire Maybe that was one of the issues but regardless of commenting out "/**": true,
    "/home/my-user-name-john-doe/**": false that I added, the problem persisted. However, disabling all extensions and enabling bare minimum solved the problem for now. Because of random nature of this error, I can't tell if the problem is "really" solved but up to now, the problem is gone!

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem is due to the directory level on which you open your file explorer.  That is, when you open the file explorer, VS code auto-fills the directory to open with /home/yourUsername.  If you accept this, then it only watches files in your home directory.  However, if you change this to the root ( / ), then it will create file watches for everything in the entire OS, and devour your system resources.

Since you're not connecting remotely as root (right?), you can't access root-level directories through the file explorer anyway.